# How to add multiple CombinedSignInAndSignUp steps in a User Journey?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I would like to make a user journey for an "on the fly password migration" use case.

I have created a custom B2C attribute, this flag tells whether the password was already migrated from the legacy system or not. If this migration flag is set I would like to execute a normal "CombinedSignInAndSignUp" step for the local account. If the flag is not set I would like call my REST API to do the migration.

I can easily implement the two steps in separate user journeys, but I couldn't make it work when the two steps are in the same user journey. If my user journey contains more than one CombinedSignInAndSignUp step I get either a validation error or an error during execution, even though I set a precondition for the steps.

How can I add two steps with the type CombinedSignInAndSignUp to one user journey? 
Or are there other ways to achieve what I would like to?
I didn't find any examples for this use case yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be implemented using preconditions within the **SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email** technical profile.

Assuming the **AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress** technical profile outputs the custom attribute, then this custom attribute can determine whether the **login-NonInteractive** or **REST-ValidateCredential** validation technical profile is invoked.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <!-- Get the migration flag of the signing-in user. -->
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
    <!-- If the migration flag is set, then authenticate against the local directory. -->
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>extension_AccountMigrated</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
          <Value>extension_AccountMigrated</Value>
          <Value>True</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
    </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
    <!-- If the migration flag isn't set, then authenticate against the remote directory. -->
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-ValidateCredential">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>extension_AccountMigrated</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
        </Precondition>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>extension_AccountMigrated</Value>
          <Value>True</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
    </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Chris. This looks exactly what I need. But I'm getting an error, it seems like AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress step has a problem with resolving the email input claim it needs. On the UI I get the error 'Unable to validate the information provided.', in Application Insights I see the error 'A claim could not be found for lookup claim with id "email" defined in technical profile with id "AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" policy "B2C_1A_signup_signin" of tenant...'. Do you have an idea what I'm missing? Should the email name ("signInNames.emailAddress") be available there?

Comment: Update: I managed to make it work by adjusting AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress technical profile by using this input claim:             <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" /> instead of             <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />. Do you think this is the right approach?

Comment: Hi @TamasMolnar. **AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress** might be invoked from elsewhere so it might be better to copy the exitsing **AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress** TP as a new **AAD-UserReadUsingSignInName** TP and then refer to this new TP as the validation TP.

Comment: Right, that was I ended up doing. My other problem was with the proposed solution that after my "REST-ValidateCredential" step the credentials were still validated by B2C. Example: the user password is not migrated yet, my REST API is called and returns OK, afterwards still validates the B2C credentials and might say that the password doesn't match (since I didn't migrate the password in my REST API). I had to adjust how I use "SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email", so that B2C doesn't validate. Thanks for the help!